# about internal direct products of multiplicative group of positive real numbers

Tags: group-theory

Can the multiplicative group of positive real numbers be written as the internal direct product of two of its subgroups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ with addition(via the isomorphism $x\rightarrow \log(x)$ ).

Think of $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$.

Let $\{b_i| i\in I\}$ be a basis, then for every subset $J$ of $I$ you have that $\mathbb R$ is the direct sum of $span \{a_i | j\in J\}$ and $span \{a_j | j\in I\setminus J\}$

Comment: does uncountable composition of elements of a group make sense ? How shall we define it ?

Comment: no it does not, but it is not needed, the basis only takes finite sums, evene if the basis itself is infinite.

Comment: But in the case of vector space consisting all real sequences, there are elements which are represented by countably infinite linear sums.

Answer (score 0):

It is isomorphic to the additive group of $\Bbb R$. Assuming the Axiom
of Choice, $\Bbb R$ has a Hamel basis, that is a basis of $\Bbb R$
as a $\Bbb Q$-vector space. Now break this Hamel basis in two...

Comment: does composition of elements of a group uncountable times make sense ? How shall we define it ?